# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ndxzsite' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: php, string

I am a beginner in php. Can someone please help me with this error!
Can not find the problem...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ndxzsite' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /customers/0/6/5/nadianena.com/httpd.www/index.php on line 10

So in looked in my editor KOMODO and it indeed says there is a parse error in this line:

```
if (file_exists('ndxzsite/config/config.php')) require_once 'ndxzsite/config/config.php';
```

Comment: It's probably a misplaced quote on a line before that

Comment: these are the lines before that: // because we are backwards compatible
ini_set('display_errors', 'On’);

// the basics

Comment: I don't know if that is clear.. could you see what is wrong with them?